# Xamarin: Listview with Recycle Element and dynamic row heights

Tags: listview, xamarin, caching

I am currently developing a chat app like whatsapp.

Everything works fine, except for the caching strategy. I want to use recycle element as it seems to work the smoothest in my scenario.

I use a Date Template Selector and my listview is set to hasunevenrows = true (due to changing message lenghts).

The Problem is that longer multiline messages get cut off as soon as I scroll the list view up and then down again. I figured that it has something to do with the reusing of my viewcells (recycle element) but I just don't understand why the listview doesn't recalculate the heights to fit the message content.

I am using bindings and this is my listview:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RetainElement" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ChatListView" IsVisible="{Binding ChatVisible}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChatList, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatSelectorTemplate}" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                    <ListView.Behaviors>
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ChatTap}" Converter="{StaticResource TappedItemConverter}" />
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemAppearing" Command="{Binding ItemAppearingEvent}" Converter="{StaticResource ItemAppearingConverter} " />
                    </ListView.Behaviors>
                </ListView>
```

The problematic DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OtherTemplate">
            <local:CustomViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="5" Padding="0,5,0,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ff:CachedImage LoadingPlaceholder="nopic.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DownsampleToViewSize="True" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding ProfilePic}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                            <ffTransformations:CircleTransformation />
                        </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                    </ff:CachedImage>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="15,10,15,10" BackgroundColor="#eaeaea" CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="False">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="3">
                            <Label TextColor="#616161" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="SourceSansPro-Semibold"/>
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.ttf#SourceSansPro-Semibold"/>
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                            <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="#828282" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Text}">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="SourceSansPro-Regular"/>
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf#SourceSansPro-Regular"/>
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="3" WidthRequest="40" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                        <Label TextColor="#828282" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Time}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="SouceSansPro-Regular"/>
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf#SourceSansPro-Regular"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </local:CustomViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Any help is appreciated as I really don't wanna stick with "RetainElement".

PS: I tested it on Android

Thanks :)

Comment: maybe you could use `Cell.ForceUpdateSize` method to programmatically resize a ListView row at runtime,you could refer to: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/DynamicUnevenListCells

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: try to set  `HasUnevenRows = true, RowHeight = -1`

Comment: if still  no effect,could you share a test project ？